# Spring app with React UI - how to serve when @EnableWebMvc is applied?

Tags: java, spring

So I have a React app I want to serve from my Spring app (ala [this blog](https://blog.indrek.io/articles/serving-react-apps-from-spring-boot/)). As part of my gradle build task, I run the `npm build` command and copy the resulting files to `/build/resources/main/static`. This works fine and I can access my app at `mysite.com/index.html`, but I want to control who has access more granularly. As such, I applied `@EnableWebMvc` to my app, but from there, I can't seem to get my API controller to actually serve the view from the build directory. It seems no matter where I put it, it doesn't like serving directly from /build. Any way to make this work?

The handler looks like:

```
@Controller
class MyController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
    fun index(): String {
        return "index"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.auto-configuration), you do not need - in fact, it is not recommended - to use `@EnableWebMvc` when using Spring Boot. They state, when describing Spring MVC auto-configuration:

> Spring Boot provides auto-configuration for Spring MVC that works well with most applications.

And:

> If you want to keep those Spring Boot MVC customizations and make more MVC customizations (interceptors, formatters, view controllers, and other features), you can add your own `@Configuration` class of type `WebMvcConfigurer` but **without** @EnableWebMvc.

In the guide, they continue when describing [static content handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.static-content):

> By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called `/static` (or `/public` or `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources`) in the classpath or from the root of the `ServletContext`. It uses the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` from Spring MVC so that you can modify that behavior by adding your own `WebMvcConfigurer` and overriding the `addResourceHandlers` method.

In your example, following this advice, you can indicate the static resource handling location with something like (sorry, I am not fluent in Kotlin, forgive for write the example in Java):

```java
@Controller
public class MyController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static")
    ;
  }

  @GetMapping(path = "/")
  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

Please, adapt the paths in `addResourceHandlers` to your needs.

You can of course place this method in an ad hoc `@Configuration`.

Having said that, if when you say *granular* you mean security, the best approach you can take is to configure Spring Security and provide the necessary authorization rules: please, see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.6.0-M1/reference/html5/#servlet-authorization).